# How to log event in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, logging

I'm trying to trigger a function on a cell in a particular column being edited. I'm trying to work out what parameters are available for me to work with, but I can't seem to log them. I have created the following which I've taken from here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  console.log(e);
  Browser.msgBox('somethign was edited');
}
```

If I edit a column, I get the pop-up, but there's nothing logged in the Execution Log. How do I get the data to show in the Execution Log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to get the parameters:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

After copying this into the script editor and saving it with no errors.  Just go to any page and perform a manual edit.  Then come back to script editor and view executions you can access it from the menu to the left in the new editor.  Read the info section of the top entry and it should contain the JSON of the event object

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't appear to do anything either.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking in the wrong place, I hadn't seen the executions menu on the left.